# Volume of the intersection and union of two spheres

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry

I'd like to calculate the volume of the intersection and the union of

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 9, {x, y, z}];
R2 = ImplicitRegion[(-1/2 + x)^2 + (y + 1/3)^2 + (z - 8)^2 <= 49, {x, y, z}];
```

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
Volume[RegionIntersection[R1, R2]]
```

> `22.5624`

```
Volume[RegionUnion[R1, R2]]
```

> `1527.29`

The above numerical results are sufficient in most of the cases, but not in all the cases. Not only
for sportive interest
(e.g. see [that thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280217/volume-of-a-finite-union-of-overlapping-balls/280222#280222)),
I want to find exact results. Of course, I am aware of [a spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap).

I find the only [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146539/drawing-and-computing-area-of-intersection-for-implicit-regions)
in this forum. However, the advice of @J. M.'s slightly less busy there to use

```
CylindricalDecomposition[x^2+y^2+z^2<=9&&(-1/2+x)^2+(y+1/3)^2+(z-8)^2<=49,{x,y,z}]
```

> `(x == (2631 - 2 Sqrt[1288846631])/27804 &&  y == (-877 + 36 x)/13848 -  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] &&  z == Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2]) || ((2631 - 2 Sqrt[1288846631])/27804 <  x < (2631 + 2 Sqrt[1288846631])/ 27804 && ((y == (-877 + 36 x)/13848 -  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] &&  z == Sqrt[ 9 - x^2 - y^2]) || ((-877 + 36 x)/13848 -  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] <  y < (-877 + 36 x)/13848 +  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] &&  8 - 1/6 Sqrt[1751 + 36 x - 36 x^2 - 24 y - 36 y^2] <= z <=  Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2]) || (y == (-877 + 36 x)/13848 +  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] &&  z == Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2]))) || (x == ( 2631 + 2 Sqrt[1288846631])/27804 &&  y == (-877 + 36 x)/13848 -  1/577 Sqrt[2222039 + 63144 x - 333648 x^2] &&  z == Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2])`

seems to be only good wishes: I have strong doubts whether Mathematica is able to calculate those triple integrals
in cartesian coordinates.

So the question is, how to exactly calculate these volumes?

Addition. In view of a valuable comment of @J. M.'s slightly less busy

```
R3 = ImplicitRegion[(1/2 + x)^2 + (y - 1/3)^2 + (z - 8)^2 <= 49, {x, 
y, z}];
Volume[RegionUnion[RegionUnion[R1, R2], R3]]
```

> `1709.77`

in a long time.

PS. The command

```
Volume[CSGRegion[ "Union", {CSGRegion[
 "Union", {Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Ball[{1/2, -1/3, 8}, 7]}], 
Ball[{-1/2, 1/3, 8}, 7]}]] // Timing
```

crashes my comp in few dozen minutes.

Comment: Nowadays, one would do something like `Volume[CSGRegion["Union", {Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Ball[{1/2, -1/3, 8}, 7]}]]` or `Volume[CSGRegion["Intersection", {Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Ball[{1/2, -1/3, 8}, 7]}]]`. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work yet for more than two spheres. The MO thread you link to is a little related to why I asked [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206269).

Comment: @J. M.: Thank you so much.  Please, convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: For older version without `CSGRegion` use `Region*` commands; [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYEla.png). But what if an implicit region didn't fit a named primitive?

Comment: @Sved: Thank you. Can you elaborate your comment?

Comment: I tried to run the commands in the OP and my i5-3rd gen 8GB computer kept spinning for several minutes and I stopped the first calculation. I was wondering if the newer versions manifest better performance with `ImplicitRegion` calculations. Please add how much time it took to finish the two calculations that you show in your post.

Comment: @Sved: On a fresh kernel `Volume[RegionIntersection[R1, R2]] // Timing` results in `{218.172, 22.5624}` on my comp.

Comment: Have you checked using geometric primitives instead? Like `{Volume@RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]], 
Volume@RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]]}`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: A good idea: even `{Volume@RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, a, z}, r2]], 
 Volume@RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]]}` works. Can you present an answer, basing on your comment?

Comment: As an additional note: before region functionality came along, you'd have to evaluate something like `Integrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 9 && (-1/2 + x)^2 + (y + 1/3)^2 + (z - 8)^2 <= 49], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]` for the intersection, which did the `CylindricalDecomposition[]` mentioned in the OP behind the scenes. Needless to say, this takes a **really** long time...

Comment: Dear colleagues: I prefer answers over valuable comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the anylytical volume of intersection with variable transformation.

Transform center of R2 ball into z direction

```
R1[{x_, y_, z_}] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 9;
R2[{x_, y_, z_}] = (-1/2 + x)^2 + (y + 1/3)^2 + (z - 8)^2 <= 49;

rot = RotationTransform[{{1/2, -1/3, 8}, {0, 0, 1}}]

(*   TransformationFunction[{{(4*(2317 + 108*Sqrt[2317]))/30121, 
    -((6*(-2317 + 48*Sqrt[2317]))/30121), -(3/Sqrt[2317]), 0}, 
   {-((6*(-2317 + 48*Sqrt[2317]))/30121), 
    (3*(6951 + 64*Sqrt[2317]))/30121, 2/Sqrt[2317], 0}, 
   {3/Sqrt[2317], -(2/Sqrt[2317]), 48/Sqrt[2317], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]   *)
```

Due to symmetrie R1 coordinates are transformed, but ball equation remains the same.

```
rot[{x, y, z}]

(*   {(4 (2317 + 108 Sqrt[2317]) x)/30121 - (6 (-2317 + 48 Sqrt[2317]) y)/
  30121 - (3 z)/Sqrt[2317], -((6 (-2317 + 48 Sqrt[2317]) x)/30121) + (
  3 (6951 + 64 Sqrt[2317]) y)/30121 + (2 z)/Sqrt[2317], (3 x)/Sqrt[
  2317] - (2 y)/Sqrt[2317] + (48 z)/Sqrt[2317]}   *)

Total@(rot[{x, y, z}]^2) // Simplify

(*   x^2 + y^2 + z^2   *)
```

Center of R2 gets stretched a little bit in z direction. Use this new center, radius remains the same.

```
{rr = rot[{1/2, -1/3, 8}] // Simplify, rr // N}

(*   {{0, 0, Sqrt[2317]/6}, {0., 0., 8.02254}}   *)

red = Reduce[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 9 && x^2 + y^2 + (z - Sqrt[2317]/6)^2 <= 49]

{int = Integrate[Boole[LogicalExpand@red], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]//Simplify, 
  int // N} // AbsoluteTiming

{4.0469006, {(740/3 - 29879687/(2592 Sqrt[2317])) \[Pi], 22.5624}}
```

Comment: +1. How about three balls? In the article cited in that thread the statement "Theoretically, we establish a formula for the volume of a restriction, based on Gauss' divergence theorem. The proof being constructive, we develop the associated algorithm" is claimed.

Comment: "Three balls?" I don't know. Could be a distorted, non-rectangular coordinate system. But I think Integrate would get stuck then.

Comment: I'd like to quote Joseph O'Rourke from that thread in my question  "This impressive work was tested on ~60,000 models in the Protein Data Bank, computing the volume of the union of sometimes more than 50,000 atoms represented as balls of different radii. Implemented in C++".

Comment: @user: none of the built-ins are yet capable of handling more than two balls, as I alluded previously. If this is important enough for you, you should bug Support so they'd have an idea about the demand.

Comment: Accepted. I can reproduce it in version 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: The result for the union is `{1298.1, (740/3 - (3 Sqrt[2233703/2317])/2 + 26469911/(
     2592 Sqrt[2317]) + 
     3 Sqrt[324 + (877 Sqrt[2233703])/4634]) \[Pi] + (
  2233703 Sqrt[2233703/2317] ArcCot[(24 Sqrt[23170])/877])/3002832 - 
  343/3 ArcCot[(1754 Sqrt[3310/7])/(35748 - Sqrt[5175489851])] + 
  343/3 ArcCot[(1754 Sqrt[3310/7])/(35748 + Sqrt[5175489851])] - (
  2233703 Sqrt[2233703/2317] ArcTan[877/(24 Sqrt[23170])])/3002832 + 
  343/3 ArcTan[(108 Sqrt[23170] - 7 Sqrt[22337030])/17540] - 
  343/3 ArcTan[(Sqrt[7/3310] (35748 + Sqrt[5175489851]))/1754]}`.

Comment: @user64494   Which can bei fullsimplified to `(740/3 + 29879687/(2592 Sqrt[2317])) Pi` . got the same with my method, integrating both spheres separately and subtracting the intersection.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like WL has some built-in answers for symbolic regions:

```
Volume @ RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]]
```

> ([Pi] (r1 + r2 - Sqrt[z^2])^2 (-3 r1^2 + 6 r1 r2 - 3 r2^2 + z^2 +
> 2 r1 Sqrt[z^2] + 2 r2 Sqrt[z^2]))/(12 Sqrt[z^2])

However, be careful because it seems like these formulas make some assumptions about the region existing in the first place. For example:

```
Volume @ RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]] /. {r1 -> 1, r2 -> 1, z -> 100}
```

> (249704 [Pi])/3

This should obviously be zero (and it is, if you do the substitution before calculating the volume):

```
Volume[
 RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]] /. {r1 -> 1, r2 -> 1, z -> 100}
 ]
```

> 0

## Edit

As halmir pointed out in the comments, you can use `GenerateConditions` to get a more reliable result:

```
Volume[
 RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]], 
 GenerateConditions -> True
]
```

Comment: +1. Thank you so much for your answer and analysis of the result.

Comment: to see the condition, Volume[RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], Ball[{0, 0, z}, r2]], 
 GenerateConditions -> True]

Comment: Even `Volume[RegionIntersection[Ball[{x1, y1, z1}, r1], 
  Ball[{x2, y2, z2}, r2]], GenerateConditions -> True]` and `Volume[RegionUnion[Ball[{x1,y1,z1},r1],Ball[{x2,y2,z2},r2]],GenerateConditions->True]` work very quickly. I think these formulas are implemented in Mathematica as table values.